# aws codebuild error on nodejs lambdas runtime

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, devops

[aws codebuild error whenver build its getting error on btoa](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uiufi.png)

./node_modules/swagger-ui-react/swagger-ui.js
Cannot find module: 'btoa'. Make sure this package is installed.

You can install this package by running: npm install btoa.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! sentinel-connect-admin@0.1.0 build: `npm run build-css && react-scripts build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the sentinel-connect-admin@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2022-06-02T09_04_35_122Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! sentinel-connect-admin@0.1.0 build:dev: `env-cmd -f .env.dev npm run-script build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the sentinel-connect-admin@0.1.0 build:dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2022-06-02T09_04_35_139Z-debug.log

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow , Can you add more context to the question, also, consider adding [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.